# Add a hyperlink to stockChart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am looking for the options to add a hyperlink to the stock chart. So that a user can click anywhere on the chart and redirect to another page.

**Not on the series, I would like to add hyperlink on the chart itself.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to call function on your highchart container div.You can use following function.

```
$("#container").on("click", function(){
window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
 // You can also use if not cross domain request
 //window.location.href='http://google.com';

});
```

Refer [this fiddle link for example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/qf3escqn/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply make your rendering element an `<a>` element with a `href` attribute pointing to where you wish to take users (just like any other hyperlink). Just make sure that this `<a>` element has a `display` property set as *block*:

```js
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<a href="http://example.com" id="container" style="height: 200px"></a>
```

Note that for this example I've used Highcharts' own [Basic Line Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/) demo.